# Drupal 8 separate pages for separate taxonomy terms

Tags: theming, 8

I have two taxonomies. I want different page templates for each taxonomy term page. Lets call the taxonomies as `taxonomy_one` and `taxonomy_two`.

When I go to taxonomy term twig debug suggests following names:

```
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
* page--taxonomy--term--2.html.twig
* page--taxonomy--term--%.html.twig
* page--taxonomy--term.html.twig
* page--taxonomy.html.twig
x page.html.twig
-->
```

Is there any way to override the taxonomy term page template by adding twig file such as:

`page--taxonomy-one--term.html.twig`?

Comment: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_theme_suggestions_alter/8.2.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found answer and posting it here in case someone needs it.

To do this you need to create the following function in your `your_template.theme` file:

```
use Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term;

function stravel_theme_suggestions_page_alter(&$suggestions, &$vars) {
  if (\Drupal::routeMatch()
      ->getRouteName() == 'entity.taxonomy_term.canonical' && $tid = \Drupal::routeMatch()
      ->getRawParameter('taxonomy_term')
  ) {
    $term = Term::load($tid);
    $suggestions[] = 'page__taxonomy__' . $term->getVocabularyId();
  }
}
```

This allows you to create page templates such as `page--taxonomy--mytaxonomy.html.twig` to display single term data. Now you can easily add regions, blocks and views as usual.

**However,
to display data related to the relevant term, you need to add contextual filters.**